# Cannot find object from a nested object in an array using _.find in sails

Tags: javascript, sails.js, lodash

I'm trying to find the value of an object using _.find in sails and somehow the returned result is undefined. I've checked with their [documentation](http://lodash.com/docs) and it seems I am doing everything right. But it is still returning undefined. I badly need your help. Thank you.

```
var obj = [
            {
              profile: {
                  profileId: 12,
                  firstName: 'John',
                  lastName: 'Doe',
                  email: 'johndoe@mail.com',
                  }
            },
            {
              profile: {
                  profile: 13,
                  firstName: 'Jane',
                  lastName: 'Doe',
                  email: 'janedoe@mail.com',
                  }
             }
           ];
var fnd = _.find(obj, {email: 'janedoe@mail.com'})
console.log(fnd); //result is undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your find line just has the wrong input, try this:

```
var fnd = _.find(obj, 
             {profile:
                {email: 'janedoe@mail.com'}
             });
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLy72/).

Comment: Eh, it was just a hair off : )

Answer (score 0):

You need to end with ; and if that doesn´t solve it I think you need to pass a function and then the condition, something like this

```
_.find(obj, function(profile) {
   return profile.email == 'janedoe@mail.com';
});
```

I'm not an expert but the documentation says so.